# DialogBox in Static Function

Tags: android, dialog

Im creating `AlertDialog` box on a class which is not the main `Activity` and the code below produce error on `this`. Thanks, I'm new in android app development.

```
  public static void width(){
      final CharSequence[] items = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};

      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setTitle("Pick a stroke width");
      builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
              String width;
              width = (String) items[item];
              int th = Integer.parseInt(width);
              ScreenTouchEvent.wd = th;
          }
      });
      AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
      alert.show();
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that your function needs to pass in a context.

```
public static void width(Context context){
...
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    ...
```

If that doesn't help, post your errors.

Comment: ty i used the code and come up with this:
 
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
 ...